# A question about sentence structure

Tags: sentence-construction

> Kevin Pietersen silenced by the ECB as they block a move by Sky to
>   hire him as a pundit for the Ashes over fears of his criticism

Above is a headline from a newspaper. I suspect some phrases in it are either incorrectly placed or not punctuated as they should be. For instance, the phrase 'over fears of his criticism' is far removed from the part it modifies, which, I guess, would be 'silenced by the ECB'. Alternatively, it could also be placed in the beginning of the sentence as a phrase.

Is my suspicion correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase *over fears of his criticism* (adverbial complement) modifies *block a move by Sky to hire him as a pundit for the Ashes* (object). The reason for its distance from the part that it modifies, is that the object is rather long.

You could rephrase it like so:

> Kevin Pietersen silenced by the ECB as they block, **over fears of his criticism**, a move by Sky to hire him as a pundit for the Ashes

So this sentence uses a normal sentence structure (except for the auxiliary that is left out, which is often done in headlines).